# Is it OK to use indentation in Windows batch files?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is this style is OK, or each line must be started from line 1st position?
It does not impact on execution, but only readability.

```
IF NOT EXIST "%AAA%" (
    FOR %%f IN (*.*) DO (
        ECHO Copying %%f
        COPY %%f "%AAA%" > NUL
    )
)
```

Comment: I just only suggest you to use 3 spaces for each identation level. 4 is too much and 2 is too few...

Comment: It is a matter of preference - I use 2 spaces all the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not only okay, but preferred.

Comment: Indentation should be OK, as all Microsoft help pages do so as well (i.e. set /?).